# Why is my string reference member variable set to an empty string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, reference, pass-by-reference

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    const string& _bar;

public:
    Foo(const string& bar)
        : _bar(bar) { }

    const string& GetBar() { return _bar; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo1("Hey");
    cout << foo1.GetBar() << endl;

    string barString = "You";
    Foo foo2(barString);
    cout << foo2.GetBar() << endl;
}
```

When I execute this code (in VS 2013), the `foo1` instance has an empty string in its `_bar` member variable while `foo2`'s corresponding member variable holds the reference to value "You". **Why is that?**

Update: I'm of course using the std::string class in this example.

Comment: Because the first one is pointing to a temporary string which was destroyed right after the call to the Foo constructor. (The temporary std::string created from the (c-)string literal "Hey")

Comment: Just pointing it out, if you use `const char *` the first case would be ok, as string literals live forever.

Comment: Btw, if your constructor was taking a non-const parameter, the first version would fail to compile because you can't bind a temporary object to a non-const ref.

Comment: @Borgleader yeah I know, that's why I made it const :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For `Foo foo1("Hey")` the compiler has to perform a conversion from `const char[4]` to `std::string`. It creates a prvalue of type `std::string`. This line is equivalent to:

```
Foo foo1(std::string("Hey"));
```

A reference bind occurs from the prvalue to `bar`, and then another reference bind occurs from `bar` to `Foo::_bar`. The problem here is that `std::string("Hey")` is a temporary that is destroyed when the full expression in which it appears ends. That is, after the semicolon, `std::string("Hey")` will not exist.

This causes a *dangling reference* because you now have `Foo::_bar` referring to an instance that has already been destroyed. When you print the string you then incur *undefined behavior* for using a dangling reference.

The line `Foo foo2(barString)` is fine because `barString` exists after the initialization of `foo2`, so `Foo::_bar` still refers to a valid instance of `std::string`. A temporary is not created because the type of the initializer matches the type of the reference.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation - there is obviously a lot going on that I do not fully comprehend yet, especially prvalue and reference bind. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 7):

You are taking a reference to an object that is getting destroyed at the end of the line with `foo1`.  In `foo2` the barString object still exist so the reference remains valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is the wonders of C++ and understanding:

1. The lifetime of objects
2. That string is a class and literal char arrays are not "strings".
3. What happens with implicit constructors.

In any case, string is a class, "Hey" is actually just an array of characters. So when you construct Foo with "Hey" which wants a reference to a string, it performs what is called an implicit conversion. This happens because `string` has an implicit constructor from arrays of characters.

Now for the lifetime of object issue. Having constructed this string for you, where does it live and what is its lifetime. Well actually for the value of that call, here the constructor of Foo, and anything it calls. So it can call all sorts of functions all over and that string is valid.

However once that call is over, the object expires. Unfortunately you have stored within your class a const reference to it, and you are allowed to. The compiler doesn't complain, because you may store a const reference to an object that is going to live longer.

Unfortunately this is a nasty trap. And I recall once I purposely gave my constructor, that really wanted a const reference, a non-const reference on purpose to ensure exactly that this situation did not occur (nor would it receive a temporary). Possibly not the best workaround, but it worked at the time.

Your best option really most of the time is just to copy the string. It is less expensive than you think unless you really process lots and lots of these. In your case it probably won't actually copy anything, and the compiler will secretly move the copy it made anyway.

You can also take a non-const reference to a string and "swap" it in

With C++11 there is a further option of using move semantics, which means the string passed in will become "acquired", itself invalidated. This is particularly useful when you do want to take in temporaries, which yours is an example of (although mostly temporaries are constructed through an explicit constructor or a return value).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in this code:

> ```
> Foo foo1("Hey");
> ```

From the string literal `"Hey"` (raw `char` array, more precisely `const char [4]`, considering the three characters in *Hey* and the terminating `\0`) a *temporary* `std::string` instance is created, and it is passed to the `Foo(const string&)` constructor.

This constructor saves a **reference** to this *temporary* string into the `const string& _bar` data member:

> ```
> Foo(const string& bar)
>         : _bar(bar) { }
> ```

Now, the problem is that you are saving a *reference* to a **temporary** string. So when the temporary string *"evaporates"* (after the constructor call statement), the reference becomes *dangling*, i.e. it references (*"points to..."*) some garbage.
So, you incur in *undefined behavior* (for example, compiling your code using MinGW on Windows with g++, I have a different result).

Instead, in this second case:

> ```
> string barString = "You";
> Foo foo2(barString);
> ```

your `foo2::_bar` reference is associated to (*"points to"*) the `barString`, which is *not* temporary, but is a local variable in `main()`. So, after the constructor call, the `barString` is still there when you print the string using `cout << foo2.GetBar()`.

Of course, to fix that, you should consider using a `std::string` data member, instead of a reference.
In this way, the string will be *deep-copied* into the data member, and it will persist even if the input source string used in the constructor is a temporary (and *"evaporates"* after the constructor call).